# Why can't I assign zero to height of a display object in Corona?

Tags: attributes, height, coronasdk

I created a bar with display.newRect() and it's okey to create this rectangle by giving zero value to height parameter. Afterwards, I wrote increaseBar and decreaseBar functions. However,  after increasing height, I tried to decrease it but height attribute of the object doesn't accept zero in assignment. Why is that?

I also checked with this simple code and same thing happens:

```
 foo = display.newRect(200,100,30,50)
 foo.height=0
```

Comment: From the Corona docs I found: "Setting a new height or width of a display object will always expand or shrink the object from the center no matter where the reference point on the object is set."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work with corona SDK. So, if you want to make the height to be zero, assign it to a value near zero.

**eg:**

```
foo.height = 0.001
```

**or**

```
foo.height = 0.01
```

Keep Coding....................... :)

Comment: Thanks, I used alpha attribute instead.